# Using SBCL's profiler in my own package

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I want to profile some code in my package. If I `(require :sb-sprof)` in REPL (from the default `CL-USER` package), it works. However, if I put this for in the code inside my package, I get `Package SB-SPROF does not exist` error.

If I put `(:import-from #:sb-sprof with-profiling)` directive in my `defpackage`, it leads to `The name "SB-SPROF" does not designate any package`.

So, how can I enable profiling?

Comment: This lacks the actual detail to really diagnose the problem: expressions, execution and the actual error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to evaluate the `require` before you do the `defpackage` of your own package. The `defpackage` won't automatically `require` the `SB-PROF` module for you. Think of `require` as some kind of "fancy" `load`, which loads the module into the image. During loading, the module's packages get created, and only after that are you able to reference them from within a `defpackage` or via the reader (`sb-sprof:with-profiling`).

Often, when I am too lazy to [do it](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/) [right](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/) (or if it's a "one-shot" solution), I use a small "loadup.lisp" script, which makes sure, that all my dependencies are present and then loads up my own code. This also makes sure, that the image can reliably be reproduced from in a fresh lisp.

Something along the lines of

```
;; Make sure, the dependencies are present

(ql:quickload '(whatever))             ;; Load a dependency via Quicklisp
(require :sb-something-else)           ;; ... or via some implementation-dependent repository
(asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op 'some-module)  ;; ... or via ASDF or ... or ... or ...

;; Now, load my own stuff 

(load "packages")
(load "something-important-1")
...
```

The order of these operations is important; you cannot reference any packages from dependency modules in your own package declarations, before those modules have been properly loaded.

Comment: And what changes when I switch to my package with `in-package` so I can't `require` the module afterwards?

Comment: Why can't you require it? The `:import-from` option of `defpackage` does **not** `require` anything; it expects the stuff (packages, symbols) referenced to be already loaded into the image! What's the exact error? When does it happen?

Comment: If I try to call `(require :sb-sprof)` after the `(in-package #:my-package)`, I get `READ error during COMPILE-FILE: Package SB-SPROF does not exist.`

Comment: @tempestadept: You need to require the package, not compile the require operation. If you want to execute a REQUIRE operation during compile time, use EVAL-WHEN.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand that problem